# Задача по массивам

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Всем привет!

Только учусь прогать, мне нужно написать программу, которая заполнит массив $triangle следующим обарзом:
в первой ячейке должен находиться массив из одного элемента — единицы
во второй ячейке должен находиться массив из двух элементов — двоек
в третьей ячейке — массив из трех троек

Всего в этом массив должно быть 9 элементов.

После того, как заполните этот массив, нужно вывести его на экран.

Попробовал так, но ничего не работает.

```
<?php

for ($i=1; $i<=9; $i++)
{
    for ($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++)
        {
        $number[]=$i
        }  
}


$triangle=[$number[$i]]
for ($k=0;$k<10;$k++)
{
    echo $triangle[$k];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: `;` в нужных местах Пушкин будет ставить? Читайте ошибки компилятора и исправляйте

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++){
     for ($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++){
        $triangle[$i][] = $i;
    }   
}
print_r($triangle);
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 6
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 7
            [6] => 7
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 8
            [5] => 8
            [6] => 8
            [7] => 8
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 9
            [4] => 9
            [5] => 9
            [6] => 9
            [7] => 9
            [8] => 9
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

как альтернативный вариант для изучения.

Строим массив:

```
$data = array_map(function($i){
                    return array_fill(0, $i, $i);
                }, range(1,9));
```

объединяем в строку и выводим

```
$result = implode("\n", array_map('implode', $data));
print_r($result);
```

получаем

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```